# Help me Evaluate this Integral

Tags: integration

I have this problem $\int \frac {-5x + 11}{{(x+1)(x^2+1)}} \text{d}x$

And i'm not sure how to deal with this. I've tried substitution and getting nowhere. I've peeked at the answer and there a trigonometric part with arctan. Do i use Partial fraction expansion here?

Thanks

Comment: yes try partial fraction and show you work then someone will help you accordingly.

Comment: KimR I am not one of the downvoters, but you should try to specify a bit on what your problem is.

Comment: It's specified in the comments below. I can edit my question with my specific problem. Even though it's solved now.

Comment: I prefer to guide the student, a solution does not help as much as finding the solution yourself.

Comment: Very correct and i agree with you. The specifics i needed help with was the part where you get (Ax + B) + C. I'm used to only work with expressions where A + B + C. I'm not quite sure why i need to use the Ax + B yet. but when i did i solved the problem on my own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the partial fraction to get
$$\frac{-5x+11}{(x+1)(x^2+1)}=\frac{3-8x}{x^2+1}+\frac{8}{x+1}=\frac{3}{x^2+1}-\frac{8x}{x^2+1}+\frac{8}{x+1}$$

#### details:

$$\frac{-5x+11}{(x+1)(x^2+1)}=\frac{Ax+B}{x^2+1}+\frac{C}{1+x}=\frac{(Ax+B)(1+x)+C(x^2+1)}{(x^2+1)(1+x)}$$
$$\frac{-5x+11}{(x+1)(x^2+1)}=\frac{Ax+Ax^2+B+Bx+Cx^2+C}{(x^2+1)(1+x)}$$
$$A+B=-5$$

$$A+C=0$$
$$B+C=11$$

solve these simultaneous equations to get
$A=-8$
$B=3$
$C=8$
so the integral will be
$$\int (\frac{3}{x^2+1}-\frac{8x}{x^2+1}+\frac{8}{x+1})dx=3\tan^{-1}x-4\log(x^2+1)+8\log(x+1)+C $$

Comment: Ok, i've done the partial fraction and got this:
-5x + 11 = A(x^2+1) + B(x+1)

And A = 8.. i struggle to find B..

Comment: @KimR $\frac{-5x+11}{(x+1)(x^2+1)}=\frac{Ax+B}{x^2+1}+\frac{C}{1+x}$

Comment: Ok, i don't understand that part there. Can you please explain that?

Comment: @KimR $$\frac{Ax+B}{x^2+1}+\frac{C}{1+x}=\frac{(Ax+B)(1+x)+C(x^2+1)}{(x^2+1)(1+x)}$$

Comment: Ok, to be more specific; i dont understand how you get Ax + B. Sorry if i need this in with a tea-spoon but i feel that hard to grasp. Does it have something to do with the original expression (-5x +11)?

Comment: @KimR, ok I will complete my answer

Comment: Ok, i've done some reading and found out when i should use Ax + B. (Heavesides Method) . Now i got the expression you wrote. That explained alot to me, thanks for your time @Hard

Comment: The basic here is that 
$$\frac{a}{b} + \frac{c}{d} = \frac{ad}{bd}+\frac{cb}{db} = \frac{ad+bc}{bd}$$